# How to output <Type> inside T4 template

Tags: c#, code-generation, t4

I am trying to implement a `T4 template` to generate some redundant `csharp` code. My template gets object type passed in as following `GenericTextFormatter<<#=type>>` where type is `typeof(objectA)` etc. So I expected generated output of `GenericTextFormatter<ObjectA>` however the template is having trouble displaying the outer angled brackets and, instead, I see no output for this part.

Comment: t4 is _text_ template, so you should pass to output not `type` object, but type name, or type full name

Comment: The problem is described above with the code that is causing my problem. I am sure someone knowledgeable with T4 templates must have seen this before.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot the closing #. Try `GenericTextFormatter<<#=type #>>`.

As a reference, the following t4 code outputs `List<System.String>`:

```
<#@ template debug="false" hostspecific="false" language="C#" #>
<#@ assembly name="System.Core" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Linq" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Text" #>
<#@ import namespace="System.Collections.Generic" #>
<#@ output extension=".txt" #>

<#
    var type = typeof(string);
#>

List<<#= type #>>
```

Comment: That was it, completely lost my concentration, thank you!